# Не показывается правая граница поля поиска

Tags: дефект, дизайн

В случае наличия вертикальной прокрутки на странице у поля поиска не показывается правая граница до момента установки в него фокуса:

[image: скринвидео]

**Google Chrome**   75.0.3770.100 (Официальная сборка) (64 бит) (cohort: Stable)
**Версия**  cd0b15c8b6a4e70c44e27f35c37a4029bad3e3b0-refs/branch-heads/3770@{#1033}
**ОС**  Windows 10 OS Version 1809 (Build 17763.557)
**JavaScript**  V8 7.5.288.23

Comment: Похоже это только у модераторов?

Comment: @vp_arth, в режиме инкогнито не воспроизводится. И вообще воспроизводится не на всех страницах. Точнее не знаю.

Comment: @vp_arth Нет, у меня точно также. Не только у модераторов.

Comment: Да, я тоже увидел, когда вернул масштаб к 100%. Похоже на баг отрисовки браузера, потому что любое изменение с откатом в css устраняет проблему. Думаю, что это из-за вот этого скачка вбок)